# Email header of an email sent from one email ID to the same email ID

Tags: email-spoofing

The SPF and DKIM Signature fields are missing in the email header when an email is sent from one email ID to the same email ID. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DKIM headers are usually added by some but not all mail servers for outgoing mail, i.e. mail leaving the domain. SPF headers are added by some but not all mail servers for external mail entering a domain. In your case the mail is only sent from one account to the same account so it probably never passes an outgoing nor an incoming mail server and thus these headers don't get added.

Comment: So when a mail is sent from one email id to the same email id what is the network path which is followed if it does not pass through any incoming or outgoing mail server?

Comment: @MartinGodfrey: this depends on how the mail is sent. If two clients in a company send a mail to each other from inside the company it will probably only pass the companies internal mail server. Same is one is sending a mail to itself. If it is possible to send mail with the companies domain as sender from outside it will be different but it depends on the actual setup.

Answer (score 0):

As a general answer:

SPF: [Sender Policy Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) and DKIM: [DomainKeys Identified Mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) are one of many security features in modern mail systems.

These ensure the Sender is properly authenticated by the outgoing mail-server.

SPF is currently almost a standard whereas DKIM is yet to become one.

As for your question:

> The SPF and DKIM signatures are missing in the email header, when an email is sent from one email ID to the same email ID. What is the reason for this?

There may be multiple reasons, among those are usually [Spam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spam), or simply misconfiguration on the server's side.

For example I had no SPF record some weeks ago on my own domain's email, I had to manually configure the DNS on my hosting provider. And DKIM I will probably have in a year, no kidding, my provider does not plan to implement it in the following months.